# Export pandas dataframe to dictionary as tuple keys and value

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
A       X       1 
B       Y       2
C       Z       3
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary with `col1` and `col2` as a tuple key and col3 as value. So, the output would look like this:

```
{
 ('A', 'X'): 1,
 ('B', 'Y'): 2,
 ('C', 'Z'): 3
}
```

How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df.set_index(['col_1', 'col_2']).apply(dict, axis=1).reset_index(name='new_key')
df.drop(labels=['col_1', 'col_2'], axis=1)
```